# Syncdb not working - django cache issue

Tags: django, postgresql, django-syncdb

I've dropped all tables from my postgres db. Now, while running

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I'm getting error that abc fields doesn't exist in xyz table.
It's probably some sort of django cache issue. Error is of this format:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "mmb_data_genre" does not exist
LINE 1: ...b_data_genre"."id", "mmb_data_genre"."genre" FROM "mmb_data_...
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Note - I'm using django 1.8.2 and

```
python manage.py makemigratons
```

or

```
python manage.py runserver
```

is throwing same error.

Comment: This may be due to migrations, before syncing db, you just delete all migrations folder inside you app.

Comment: I've deleted migrations folders from apps

Comment: Try deleting all migrations in `django_migrations` table then run `python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: I've dropped my entire db which includes this table as well.

Comment: Try deleting any and all .pyc files in your project.

Comment: already tried with this.. still no luck

Answer (score 1):

[syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) in django 1.8 is merely an alias for the migrate command but with the additional step of creating a superuser.

> Deprecated since version 1.7: This command has been deprecated in
>   favor of the migrate command, which performs both the old behavior as
>   well as executing migrations.

But syncdb (migrate) should be executed only after you have done makemigrations [app_label] but in your case you seem to have the order in reverse.

Try

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Running ./manage.py makemigrations is also throwing same error

Comment: If this is a new database, clear it and clear the migrations folder and try those two steps.